# For which problems Krylov subspace methods are preffered over multigrid methods?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, multigrid

As multigrid methods are known to have grid independent convergence rates with $O(N)$ computational cost, then why would one be interested in using Krylov subspace methods at all, for which convergence rates deteriorate with grid refinement? Are there any problems where Krylov solvers perform better than MG methods?

Comment: For many problems Krylov subspace methods perform much better than $O(N)$ at least if you just need an approximate solution. Say you have two big clusters of eigenvalues in a matrix equation system you are about to solve. In just 2-3 iterations most of the residual error / conjugate directions will have been eaten away no matter how many discretized points (matrix size) you have.

Comment: How do you solve your linear system on each grid? A good answer is . . . Krylov subspace methods!